# How to display CKEditor with Codeblock plugin in React App

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm asking for help with a very specific problem with CKEditor5 in React.
I'm able to implement the basic CKEditor5 in my React project, with the code right here:
(The code may not be clean, I'm learning React on my own and doing some projects on my own, I don't have all the concepts yet, so please be understanding if possible.)

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const Edittuto = () => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState<any>('');
    const [text, setText] = useState<any>('');
    const { id } = useParams();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("UseEffect")
  
      const editorPlaceholder = document.querySelector( '#editor' ) as HTMLElement;
  
      ClassicEditor
        .create( editorPlaceholder, {
        })
  
      [...]
    }, [])
  
    const handleUpdate = (event: any) => { ... }
  
    const handleSubmit = (event: any) => { ... }
  
    return (
      <div className="container edit-container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <h1 className="text-center">Edit un tutoriel</h1>
            <form>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="titre">Titre du tutoriel</label>
                <input type="text" name="titre" className="form-control" id="titre" value={title} onChange={handleUpdate} placeholder="Titre du tutoriel" />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="contenu">Contenu du tutoriel</label>
                <div className="ckeditor">
                  <div id="editor"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Edittuto;
```

So my CKEditor displays fine, no problem on this side. However, I don't have the option to add code. From what I've seen, I need to install the plugin (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/code-blocks.html)

So I follow the integration tutorial for this plugin, I have to modify the code in certain places (Marked with //--Changed:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor'; //--Changed
import CodeBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock'; //--Changed

const Edittuto = () => {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState<any>('');
    const [text, setText] = useState<any>('');
    const { id } = useParams();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("UseEffect")
  
      const editorPlaceholder = document.querySelector( '#editor' ) as HTMLElement;
  
      ClassicEditor
        .create( editorPlaceholder, {
          plugins: [ CodeBlock ], //--Changed
        })
  
        [...]
    }, [])
  
    const handleUpdate = (event: any) => { ... }
  
    const handleSubmit = (event: any) => { ... }
  
    return (
      [...]
    );
  };
  
  export default Edittuto;
```

However, I encounter a bug, my CKEditor does not display at all, and when I do console.log() to see if it is initialized, it tells me it is.
Has anyone worked with CKEditor5 in React before and could tell me where the problem might come from? If not, is there a WYSIWYG alternative with code block option?

I really want to solve this bug, I've done internet research but I haven't really found a solution.
If it can help, the project was initialized with Vite.